# File Output issue in PowerShell

Tags: date, powershell, logging, file-io

Trying to write to a log file assigned to a variable in PowerShell, like so-

**Code:**

```
$Time = Get-Date
$FileTimeStamp = (Get-Date -f MM-dd-yyyy_HH.mm.ss)
$ErrorLog | out-file $(".\Logs\" + $FileTimeStamp + "_PushLog.log") -append

"Script started at $Time" | out-file $ErrorLog -append
```

**Compile error-**

```
Out-File : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'FilePath' because it is null.
At C:\OSM\Scripts\FilePush\FilePush.ps1:56 char:37
+ "Script started at $Time" | out-file <<<< $ErrorLog -append
+ CategoryInfo : InvalidData: ( [Out-File], ParameterBindingValidationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.OutFileCommand
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I getting there? It's now correctly writing one file instead of two, but the log doesn't contain the string "Session started at $Time".

**Code:**

```
$Time = Get-Date
$FileTimeStamp = (Get-Date -f HH.mm.ss_MM-dd-yyyy)

$ErrorLog = out-file $(".\Logs\" + $FileTimeStamp + "_PushLog.log") -append
$ErrorLog = [io.path]::GetFileName("$ErrorLog.FullName") 
"Session started at $Time" | out-file $ErrorLog -append
```

The whole point of what I'm trying to do is create a variable for an error file that I can reference when I want to output text to it. I only want log each time the script runs, but that seems to be an issue when I;'m appending the time to the file name. How do I work past this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bob answered the question but really didn't help provide a solution, so I'll add an answer.

The issue is that when you try to define your `$ErrorLog` variable you're overthinking it. You just need to create a string that defines where the file is located, not have all the Out-File and -Append on that line.

```
$Time = Get-Date
$FileTimeStamp = (Get-Date -f MM-dd-yyyy_HH.mm.ss)
$ErrorLog = ".\Logs\$FileTimeStamp_PushLog.log"
"Script started at $Time" | out-file $ErrorLog -append
```

Comment: Thanks guys. I wasn't able to get it to do what I wanted with the line-

' $ErrorLog = ".\Logs\$FileTimeStamp_PushLog.log '

But the following works perfectly-

$Time = Get-Date
$FileTimeStamp = (Get-Date -f MM-dd-yyyy_HH.mm.ss)
$ErrorLog = ".\Logs\" + $FileTimeStamp + "_PushLog.log"
"Script started at $Time" | out-file $ErrorLog -append

Thanks again!

Comment: So did you still need help with something, or is your question answered?

Comment: Nope, you both did a great job at helping me out, I'm just trying to figure out to format comment editing. 'code' doesn't seem to work...

Anyway, thanks again! I'd vote you up but apparently I need 15 posts first.

Comment: Oh, just FYI... code highlighting in comments is done by enclosing the desired text between the grave character (to the left of the 1 key on your keyboard). It looks like a single quote, but it's different. Have a great weekend!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't defined $ErrorLog.